# Save Data in Firebase Realtime Database Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How can I save all data fields of my user signup form in Firebase Realtime database on Android Studio using language Kotlin?

Currently my app is successfully registering accounts but I also want custom fields like cnic, number, platenumber and name of the user to be stored on firebase Realtime database. The Working code is below.

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //view binding
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding

    //action bar
    private lateinit var actionBar: ActionBar

    //progression bar
    private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

    //firebase auth
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private var name = ""
    private var email = ""
    private var password = ""
    private var platenumber = ""
    private var number = ""
    private var cnic = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //config actionbar enable back button
        actionBar = supportActionBar!!
        actionBar.title = "Sign Up"
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        //config progress dialog
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Wait Please")
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating account...")
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

        //init firebaseauth
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        //handle click begin signup
        binding.signupButton.setOnClickListener {
            //validate data
            validateData()
        }


    }

    private fun validateData() {
        //get data
        name = binding.nameET.text.toString().trim()
        email = binding.emailET.text.toString().trim()
        password = binding.passwordET.text.toString().trim()
        platenumber = binding.dobET.text.toString().trim()
        number = binding.numberET.text.toString().trim()
        cnic = binding.cnicET.text.toString().trim()

        //validate data
         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            //no password entered
            binding.nameET.error = "Enter Name"
        }
        else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            //invalid email
            binding.emailET.error = "Invalid Email"
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            // no password entered
            binding.passwordET.error = "Enter Password"
        }

        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(platenumber)){
        // no password entered
            binding.dobET.error = "Enter Vehicle Plate Number"
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(number)){
        // no password entered
            binding.numberET.error = "Enter Contact Number"
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cnic)){
        // no password entered
            binding.cnicET.error = "Enter CNIC Number"
        }
        else if (password.length<6){
            binding.passwordET.error = "Enter a Password of Atleast 6 Characters"
        }
        else if (number.length<11){
            binding.passwordET.error = "Enter full 11 Digit Number"
        }
        else if (cnic.length<13){
            binding.passwordET.error = "Enter full 13 Digit CNIC Number"
        }
        else{
        //data is valid signup new user
        firebaseSignUp()
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseSignUp() {
        progressDialog.show()
        //create account
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                //signup success
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                //get current user
                val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
                val email = firebaseUser!!.email
                Toast.makeText(this, "Account  Created With Email $email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //start activity
                startActivity(Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java))
                finish()

            }
            .addOnFailureListener{ e->
                //signup fial
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signup failed due to ${e.message}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed() // go back to previous activity
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store those values for each user, you could do something like this:

```
private fun firebaseSignUp() {
    progressDialog.show()
    //create account
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { //  Change to success listener
            //signup success
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            //get current user
            val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            val email = firebaseUser!!.email

            //  create a map of value
            val profile = mapOf(
                cnic to "cnic",
                number to "number",
                platenumber to "platenumber",
                name to "name"
            )
            //  write to database
            vak database = Firebase.database.reference
            database.child("users").child(firebaseUser!!.uid).setValue(profile)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Account  Created With Email $email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //start activity
            startActivity(Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{ e->
            //signup fial
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signup failed due to ${e.message}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

I recommend also reading the Firebase documentation on [reading from and writing to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).