# How do you connect a user from firebase-authentication and the correct data in firebase-realtime-database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created my own login screen and am using the email/password login from firebase. I am able to register, login and logout of an account.
I want to be able to create and save data onto the realtime-database that then is just available with the account I was logged in while I created that data.
But I don't know how that works. I couldn't find anything that made sense to me.
If anyone has any info regarding this pls help, thx!

Comment: "I couldn't find anything that made sense to me" is really hard to help with. If you are asking [how to save user data](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+save+firebase+user+data+in+realtime+database) have a look at the search results for that. Without seeing what you tried, your question is very likely a duplicate of one of those. Such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682667 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/70036609/209103

Comment: yea you are right sorry. I think the links you provided are looking promissing so thx a lot.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time trying to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help.